# lowering output logic levels

Tags: voltage-divider

I am (planning to) use [MAX13410E](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/interface/transceivers/MAX13410E.html) in receive-only mode to convert RS485 differential level to Vo/GND voltage. The chip is outputting Voh=4.6V and Vol=0.4V (relative to GND). The RS485signal will be flipping between 0 and 1 every few seconds, not faster.

This signal will be fed into another device expecting 0...0.15V for low and 0.3...10V for high.

It is a good idea to use voltage divider with e.g. 1:5 ratio to get 4.6/6=.76V high and .4/6=.07V low? Or is there some other standard approach?

Comment: I'd suggest to use s Schmitt Trigger with the appropriate level setup

Comment: I added the note about low-rate signal. Was high rate reason for the Schmitt trigger? I am looking for a solution as simple as possible.

Comment: What is the other device?

Comment: @KevinWhite it's a controller for industrial DC servo, the logic (start/stop) voltage levels are specified by the manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

A voltage divider could be made to work fairly well if the device with the low level input has a high impedance and thus does not load the voltage divider.

If the target device is of a lower impedance nature or presents different input impedance depending upon the input voltage level then it would probably make sense to use a voltage comparator to detect the high and low thresholds of the signal from the RS485 device. As long as the comparator was an open drain device with an output low saturation level of less than 150mV you could then connect the comparator output also to a suitable pullup resistor.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of comparator, having only 24V rail available, using e.g. LM393 (up to 30V for V_in) for comparing A/B lines of the RS485 could be even easier than using a designated RS485 receiver. Can you confirm?

Comment: Sure you can make a comparator work to convert the differential bus to single ended logic. Such circuit would probably not be as robust as the specialized chip but the component cost would be way lower. If the capability specs of RS485 are applicable to your application (such as the -7 to +12V common mode range at the receiver) the dedicated part, or one similar to it, will generally be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Source: http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/rercal.php
[image]

The output will be inverted. You can handle it in the device or you can also use non inverting Schmitt trigger.

- You can balance power consumption based on actual *device* input impedance.